# Why my records are not being upserted via Mulesoft into Salesforce when SFTP record has date field = null?

Tags: java, salesforce, mulesoft

I am using Mulesoft to integrate records from SFTP to Salesforce (upsert).
In the SFTP records, a date field (Store_Close_Date__c) is sometimes null. 
This was generating java exceptions in Mulesoft, so I edited the config.xml file to transform the field.

Please find config.xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc" xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-sfdc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd">
    <sfdc:config name="UpsertProducts" username="xxxx" password="xxxx" securityToken="xxxx" url="https://xxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0" doc:name="SFTP_Products"/>
    <sftp:connector name="SFTP_Products" validateConnections="true" autoDelete="false" doc:name="SFTP_Products">
            <service-overrides messageReceiver="chalhoub.ChalhoubSftpMessageReceiverProducts"/>
    </sftp:connector>
    <sftp:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="22" name="SFTP" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"/>
    <sftp:connector name="SFTP_Locations" validateConnections="true" autoDelete="false" doc:name="SFTP_Locations">
            <service-overrides messageReceiver="chalhoub.ChalhoubSftpMessageReceiverLocations"/>
    </sftp:connector>
    <sfdc:config name="UpsertLocations" username="xxxx" password="xxxx" securityToken="xxxx" url="https://xxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/37.0" doc:name="SFTP_Locations"/>
    <flow name="Products">
        <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP_Products" host="xxxx" port="xxxx" path="//" user="xxxx" password="xxxx" responseTimeout="60000" autoDelete="false" doc:name="Get Products"/>
        <message-chunk-splitter messageSize="1000000" doc:name="Products Chunk Splitter"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Products Transform Message" metadata:id="007db759-7ccf-44fd-b053-0a67709fd56b" ><!-- metadata:id="a9bd1fde-189a-40e7-aed1-85652885c03f" -->
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    Name: payload01.ITEM_DESC,
    Product_Number__c: payload01.ITEM_NUMBER,
    Primary_VPN__c: payload01.PRIMARY_VPN,
    Department_ID__c: payload01.DEPARTMENT_ID,
    Department_Name__c: payload01.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
    Class_ID__c: payload01.CLASS_ID,
    SubClass_ID__c: payload01.SUBCLASS_ID,
    SubClass_Name__c: payload01.SUBCLASS_NAME,
    Department_Brand__c: payload01.DEPARTMENT_BRAND,
    Gender__c: payload01.GENDER,
    Season__c: payload01.SEASON,
    Size__c: payload01.SIZE,
    Color__c: payload01.COLOR,
    Line__c: payload01.LINE,
    Sub_Line__c: payload01."SUB LINE",
    Supplier_Class__c: payload01."SUPPLIER CLASS",
    Supplier_SubClass__c: payload01."SUPPLIER SUBCLASS"
})]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <sfdc:upsert-bulk config-ref="UpsertProducts" type="Product__c" externalIdFieldName="Product_Number__c" doc:name="Upsert Products ">
            <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
        </sfdc:upsert-bulk>
    </flow>
    <flow name="Locations">
        <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP_Locations" host="xxxx" port="xxxx" path="//" user="xxxx" password="xxxx" responseTimeout="60000" autoDelete="false" doc:name="Get Locations"/>
        <message-chunk-splitter messageSize="1000000" doc:name="Locations Chunk Splitter"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Locations Transform Message" metadata:id="a61e8266-246f-4cae-a372-f5fbc641e5c8">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    Name: payload01.STORE_NAME,
    Location_Code__c: payload01.STORE,
    Location_Open_Date__c: payload01.STORE_OPEN_DATE as :date{format:"dd.MM.yyyy"}  default 'null',
    Store_Close_Date__c: payload01.STORE_CLOSE_DATE as :date{format:"dd.MM.yyyy"}  default 'null',
    Mall_Name__c: payload01.MALL_NAME,
    Currency_Code__c: payload01.CURRENCY_CODE,
    Country_ID__c: payload01.COUNTRY_ID,
    Country_Description__c: payload01.COUNTRY_DESC,
    Org_Unit_ID__c: payload01.ORG_UNIT_ID,
    Org_Unit_Description__c: payload01.DESCRIPTION
})]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <sfdc:upsert-bulk config-ref="UpsertLocations" type="Location__c" externalIdFieldName="Location_Code__c" doc:name="Upsert Locations">
            <sfdc:objects ref="#[payload]"/>
        </sfdc:upsert-bulk>
    </flow>


</mule>
```

Now the issue is that only records not having Store_Close_Date__c = null are being upserted into Salesforce. This is probably from the modification I made on the config.xml file.

All records including those having Store_Close_Date__c = null should be upserted.

Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is being caused by Dataweave type casting.

When the date is null Dataweave will be unable to cast the value to a date.

Change the Dataweave field mapping to:

```
Store_Close_Date__c: (payload01.STORE_CLOSE_DATE as :date{format:"dd.MM.yyyy"}) when payload01.STORE_CLOSE_DATE != null otherwise null
```

This will ensure it does a null check first and only cast if it is not null

Keaton